# Finding more details in 1851/1861 Scotland Census?

Tags: census-records, ancestry.com, scotland, familysearch.org, dunbartonshire

I am relatively inexperienced in using **FamilySearch** to find **Scotland Census** records but I suspect the 1851 and 1861 records below may belong to my 4th great grandfather **Robert Clacher**.

My **Ancestry.com** subscription enables me to see that in the 1841 Census, he was a Slater, aged 40, living at Princes Street, Row, Dunbartonshire with his wife Mary (35; nee Campbell), and their children Margaret (14), Janet (6), Robert (3) and Marianne (1). However, these 1851 and 1861 Census records do not appear to be present there.

Can anyone offer advice on how I may be able to find out, hopefully view an image of, more details like the occupation, address, etc of Robert Clacher in the 1851 and 1861 Scotland Censuses?

---

Name:   Robert Clacker
Event Type: Census
Event Date: 1851
Gender: Male
Age:    50
Birthplace: Dumbarton
Registration District:  undefined
County: Dunbartonshire
Birth Year (Estimated): 1801
GS Film number: 1042284

Citing this Record:
"Scotland Census, 1851," index, *FamilySearch* (https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/VYYY-YMG : accessed 31 May 2014), Robert Clacker, , Dunbartonshire, Scotland; citing "1851 England, Scotland & Wales census," index and images, *findmypast.co.uk* (www.findmypast.co.uk : Brightsolid, 2012); PRO HO 107, p. 10, New Register House, Edinburgh; FHL microfilm 1042284.

---

Name:   Robert Clachers
Event Type: Census
Event Date: 1861
Gender: Male
Age:    60
Birthplace: Dunbartonshire
Registration District:  Row Parish
County: Dunbartonshire
Birth Year (Estimated): 1801
GS Film number: 103818

Citing this Record:
"Scotland Census, 1861," index, *FamilySearch* (https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/VBW6-J14 : accessed 31 May 2014), Robert Clachers, Row Parish, Dunbartonshire, Scotland; citing "1861 England, Scotland & Wales census," index and images, *findmypast.co.uk* (www.findmypast.co.uk : Brightsolid, 2012.); PRO RG 9, p. 11, New Register House, Edinburgh; FHL microfilm 103818.

Comment: Not having an international ancestry subscription, I can't give urls, but I think your guy is indexed at ancestry as Robert Clachus in the 1861 Scotland census. Ancestry has the censuses you asked for; it's probably a case of differential indexing. Any reason why wild cards in your searches or using the browse option to navigate to the cited page haven't been tried?

Comment: @bgwiehle You've exposed more of my inexperience:-) I have now located him in the 1861 Census which has him born in Kirkintilloch (just like his future wife) but wildcards have not yet helped in the 1851.  You suggest "using the browse option to navigate to the cited page" but I am not sure how to perform that - can you provide a more detailed hint perhaps as an Answer?

Comment: @bgwiehle No need for more hints because I just found him as Robert Clarke in 1851 Census with correct wife Mary and daughter Jessie - ages not exact but close and their birthplaces match too.  Thanks for pointing me firmly in right direction so if you can turn your Comment into an Answer I will be very happy to Accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not having an international ancestry subscription, I can't give urls, but I think your guy is indexed at ancestry as Robert Clachus in the 1861 Scotland census. Ancestry has the censuses you asked for; it's probably a case of differential indexing.

Try using wild cards in your searches or navigate to the cited page. Since the Scotland censuses don't have a browse option available on the right side of the page, do a search on the location only, then pick any individual and go to the image. Browse back and forwards through the images. When you find your individual, check the indexed name. Adding him to your ancestry shoebox makes accessing the record entry simple, without repeating the search.

Answer (score 3):

Images to the Scottish census records are available only on [Scotlandspeople](http://www.scotlandspeople.gov.uk/) - pay per view only. Unfortunately, finding the right image might not be simple as FamilySearch quotes FindMyPast references of the PRO RG and PRO HO format, which apply to the *English and Welsh* censuses at Kew, *not* the Scots ones. In other words they are concocted and useless.

You would do better - *I think* - to find the records in Ancestry and take note of the parish and enumeration district numbers - they do map across to ScotlandsPeople, at least in part, though I've never tried it.